# Is not including all dependencies in the useEffect dependency array an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to wrap my head around the React Hooks API. Specifically, I'm trying to construct the classic use case that once was the following:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.foo !== this.props.foo) {
        // Animate DOM elements here...
        this.animateSomething(this.ref, this.props.onAnimationComplete);
    }
}
```

Now, I tried to build the same with a functional component and `useEffect`, but can't figure out how to do it. This is what I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
    animateSomething(ref, props.onAnimationComplete);
}, [props.foo]);
```

This way, the effect is only called when `props.foo` changes. And that does work – BUT! It appears to be an anti-pattern since the `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` rule warns about this. All dependencies that are used inside the effect should be declared in the dependencies array. So that means I would have to do the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    animateSomething(ref, props.onAnimationComplete);
}, [props.foo, ref, props.onAnimationComplete]);
```

That does not lead to the linting error BUT it totally defeats the purpose of *only* calling the effect when `props.foo` changes. I DON'T want it to be called when the other props or the ref change.

Now, I read something about using `useCallback` to wrap this. I tried it but didn't get any further.

Comment: I guess that animation should not be triggered when `props.onAnimationComplete` changes. Furthermore already running `animateSomething` still will use an old callback.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would recommend writing this as follows:

```
const previousFooRef = useRef(props.foo);

useEffect(() => {
    if (previousFooRef.current !== props.foo) {
       animateSomething(ref, props.onAnimationComplete);
       previousFooRef.current = props.foo;
    }
}, [props.foo, props.onAnimationComplete]);
```

You can't avoid the complexity of having a condition inside the effect, because without it you will run your animation on mount rather than just when `props.foo` changes. The condition also allows you to avoid animating when things other than `props.foo` change.

By including `props.onAnimationComplete` in the dependencies array, you avoid disabling the lint rule which helps ensure that you don’t introduce future bugs related to missing dependencies.

Here's a working example:

[image: Edit animate]

Comment: The callback should be recreated every render. And changes to `props.onAnimationComplete` should trigger a rerender. So there is no real need for this complexity.

Comment: What complexity are you referring to? The condition is necessary to avoid animating on mount. Adding the callback to the dependencies is less complex than disabling the lint rule. It is true that it is not necessary in the dependency array currently, but there would be numerous ways this code could evolve over time where it would matter and disabling the lint rule would make future bugs more likely.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me get to the solution!

Comment: @RyanCogswell won't linter complain that you omitted `ref` from dep array?

Comment: @giorgim The linter knows that the value returned from `useRef` [does not change across renders](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.12.0/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js#L230), so refs do not need to be in the dependency array. In the sample sandbox, you can see that there are no eslint warnings, but you do get a warning if you remove `foo` from the dependency array.

Answer (score 4):

Suppress the linter because it gives you a bad advice. React requires you to pass to the second argument the values which (and only which) changes must trigger an effect fire.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    animateSomething(ref, props.onAnimationComplete);
}, [props.foo]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

It leads to the same result as the [Ryan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232908/1118709).

I see no problems with violating this linter rule. In contrast to `useCallback` and `useMemo`, it won't lead to errors in common case. The content of the second argument is a high level logic.

You may even want to call an effect when an extraneous value changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    alert(`Hi ${props.name}, your score is changed`);
}, [props.score]);
```

Comment: The reason for this linter rule is the following in your examples: 1) if `animateSomething` ever changed (i.e. you decide to change the animation speed, ...), this effect would still refer to the old function and you will most probably get an unintended result. 2) If the `name` changes, the user would still see the old name. - Maybe in the case of an alert, you should return a clean-up function that closes this alert, so that you will only show the relevant alert.

Comment: While it may be not be necessary for this example, I have found cases where, at least to me, it does seem much more desirable to override the linter than work around the behavior, particularly in the case where you wish to limit the effect to the first render by passing an empty array - which still triggers the exhaustive-deps warning.

Answer (score -1):

Move the values, that must be fresh (not stale) in the callback but mustn't refire the effect, to refs:

```js
const elementRef = useRef(); // Ex `ref` from the question
const animationCompleteRef = useRef();

animationCompleteRef.current = props.onAnimationComplete;

useEffect(() => {
    animateSomething(elementRef, animationCompleteRef.current);
}, [props.foo, elementRef, animationCompleteRef]);
```

It works because `useRef` return value doesn't change on renders.