# how to push multiple objects in react js to array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Hello I was trying to store some data in my array and I did try `allData.push(Data1, Data2, Data3)` but it said `.push` was not a function and it also didn't let me just `allData(Data1, Data2, Data3)`, w/e data I get it overrides the previous one. I also tried `allData(Data1+Data2+Data3)`

This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let x = 0;
    
    LibrosID1.map((i) => {
      x += i.precio
    })

    LibrosID2.map((i) => {
      x += i.precio
    })

    LibrosID3.map((i) => {
      x += i.precio
    })

    setAllItems(LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3)
    setSubTotal(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))

  });

// I have 3 like this the only thing that changes is variable # from 1 to 3

const [LibrosID1, setLibrosID1] = useState([]);
    const handleChange1 = (e, data) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
      // if cheked and selectall checkbox add all fileds to selectedList
      if (name === "allSelectNuevos") {
        setLibrosID1(librosNuevos);

        let x = 0
        librosNuevos.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio
          setTPLibrosNuevos(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })

      } else {
        // if cheked and specific checkbox add specific field to selectedList
        setLibrosID1([...LibrosID1, data]);

        let x = 0
        LibrosID1.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio
          setTPLibrosNuevos(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })
      }
    } else {
      // if uncheked and selectall checkbox add remove all fileds from selectedList
      if (name === "allSelectNuevos") {
        setLibrosID1([]);

        let x = 0
        librosNuevos.map((i) => {
          x = 0
          setTPLibrosNuevos(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })

      } else {
        // if uncheked and specific checkbox remove specific field from selectedList
        let tempuser = LibrosID1.filter((item) => item.id !== data.id);
        setLibrosID1(tempuser);

        let x = 0
        tempuser.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio
          setTPLibrosNuevos(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(LibrosID3, tpPaqueteCuadernos, allItems);
 }, [LibrosID1, tpLibrosNuevos])
```

In short I'm calculating my subtotal and that bit is working and now I want to store all the items I'm "buying" in allItems

This is what it prints when I click on the LibrosID1 all checkbox:

[image]

This is what it prints when I click on the LibrosID2 all checkbox:

[image]

And finally this is when I click on the last one LibrosID3 all checkbox:

[image]

As you can see it only adds the value from LibrosID1 even though I have it as `setAllItems(LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3)`

Any tips, documentation and help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code, I assume `setAllItems` should be storing the array.
To do that you need to pass an array to `setAllItems` like  `setAllItems([LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3])`

Comment: Yeah that seems to work but now I'm getting an infinite loop cause is inside an useEffect

Comment: `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

Comment: that's correct, as you are updating `allItems` inside useEffecect without any dependency which means it will run each time there is any change in state.
You can check these links. [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228102/react-hook-useeffect-dependency-array) and [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: But I'm doing exactly the same for my subTotal and that doesn't happen to my subTotal only to my allItems ... now I'm confuse.

Comment: and is not really saving data because I just double checked sending it to somewhere else any ideas ?

Comment: Consider [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share that link.

Comment: I honestly do not know how to reproduce a small version of what I'm doing all I know is that I'm getting that error as a loop this is what I'm trying to do to store the values I want: `useEffect(() => {setAllItems([LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3])}, [LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3])`